# Getting a "Table does not exist" error when trying to insert or select from a table in Mango Local Database

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, local, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to create a local database for a Windows Phone application.  I can create the database quite happily but it looks like the tables in the database are not being created or are being created with names I'm not expecting.

Is there any way to see what tables exist in the db or is there something extra I need to do to have the tables created?  Has anyone else had this problem (and how did you solve it)?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to define the database schema, and some sample code that is failing (selecting from table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.  Problem turned out to be the "Name" attributes were causing problems.  Even though the name for each column was the same as the property the attribute was covering the SQL CE db didn't like it.  I removed the attribute and the problem went away.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if it fixed your problem. So everybody knows this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look into the database is always a good start in cases like yours. You have to perform some steps, though:

1. Dump the content of your isolated storage using the [Isolated Storage Explorer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx); dumping from emulator and device both is possible
2. Find the database file (.sdf) among the files
3. Open the file in one of the available tools for connecting to SQL CE databases

Read [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/19/using-the-isolated-storage-explorer-tool-on-wp7-mango-to-export-your-sdf-file.aspx) for a complete tutorial. The tutorial uses Visual Studio for connecting to the DB, I use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).